# HTML Bug, Image not aligning to the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html file, and I am using bootstrap and Gentelella template, for some reason the only image I display in the widget is aligned to the right, and nothing that I do changes it to the middle.

Edit: For the css I am just using the regular bootstrap.min.css and the Gentella custom.css here:

```
.img-circle.profile_img {
width: 70%;
background: #fff;
margin-left: 15%;
z-index: 1000;
position: inherit;
margin-top: 20px;
border: 1px solid rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.44);
padding: 4px
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="x_panel">
  <div class="x_title">
    <h2>Summary</h2>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="x_content">
    Users sneak peek should be inserted here...
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 widget widget_tally_box">
    <div class="x_panel fixed_height_390">
      <div class="x_content">

        <div class="flex">
          <ul class="list-inline widget_profile_box text-center">
            <li>
              <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png" align="middle" class="img-circle profile_img">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h3 class="name">User Name</h3>

        <div class="flex">
          <ul class="list-inline count2">
            <li>
              <h3>123</h3>
              <span>Questions</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3>1234</h3>
              <span>Answered</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3>123</h3>
              <span>Unanswered</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <p>
          Click here to see all the detailed information about this user.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You should provide your css, or else we won't be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.list-inline` makes the `li`'s `inline-block`, you can use `.text-center` on the `ul` to center the `li`

btw, the `align` attribute is obsolete on an `img` - https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 widget widget_tally_box">
  <div class="x_panel fixed_height_390">
    <div class="x_content">

      <div class="flex">
        <ul class="list-inline widget_profile_box text-center">
          <li>
            <img src="images/user.png" class="img-circle profile_img">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h3 class="name">User Name</h3>

      <div class="flex">
        <ul class="list-inline count2">
          <li>
            <h3>123</h3>
            <span>Questions</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>1234</h3>
            <span>Answered</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>123</h3>
            <span>Unanswered</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p>
        Click here to see all the detailed information about this user.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not work, I updated the code to see if the problem is from a little above, thank you.

Comment: @DFabiano if you remove the `margin-left` from the `img`, seems centered to me... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXxRmP

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0936a3c24c2f56f556ae6bbe1f2c5a51 Mine is not working, I guess the problem is somewhere else, I really appreciate the input though.

Comment: @DFabiano you're welcome. Looks like you have some CSS somewhere else that isn't included in your post here.